# Single character parameter issue in Django url

Tags: django, django-urls

I have the following urlpattern:

```
url(r'exp/users/(?P<userid>\w.+)/$', 'myapp.views.users_view_by_id', name='users_id'),
```

When userid is a single digit (eg '1') I get a 404 Page Not Found but when it is more than a single digit the page responds as expected (eg '10').

So `'../exp/users/10/'` works fine but `'.../exp/users/1/'` returns a 404.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra `.` in your regex.

`\w.+` means "one alphanumeric character, then one or more of any character". What you want is just `\w+`, which means "one or more alphanumeric characters".

**Edit**

If you want to include a literal "." in the characters that can be accepted, use square brackets to define a class:

```
(?P<userid>[\w.]+)
```

Comment: Some ids come in with a . (for example 'user.1234'), which is why I included a . How can I handle both scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match one or more digits, then use `(?P<userid>\d+)`.

Your current regex requires one character to match `\w`', followed by at least one character to match `.+`.